# How to manage Thread Local Storage (TLS) when using TPL?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, threadpool, task-parallel-library, thread-local-storage

I want to store logging context information in TLS so that I can set a value at the entry point, and have that value available in all resulting stacks. This work well, but I also using TPL and the ThreadPool. The problem then becomes how to migrate TLS data to the other threads. I can do it all myself, but then I lose nice methods like Parallel.For.

Is there some way to have TLS copied when using TPL? This will also apply to C# when it gets the await feature.

Thanks,
Erick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, this is handled via using an overload of [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783299.aspx#Y0) that already provides for thread local data.

This overload allows you to provide an initialization and a finalization delegate, which effectively becomes an initialization per thread for your thread local data, and a reduction function at the end to "merge" the results together (which is run once per thread).  [I wrote about this in detail here](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/).

The basic form is to do something like:

```
object sync = new object();
double result = 0;

Parallel.For(0, collection.Count, 
    // Initialize thread local data:
    () => new MyThreadSpecificData(),
    // Process each item
    (i, pls, currentThreadLocalData) => 
    {
        // Generate a NEW version of your local state data
        MyThreadSpecificData newResults = ProcessItem(collection, i, currentThreadLocalData);
        return newResults;
    },
    // Aggregate results
    threadLocalData =>
    {
       // This requires synchronization, as it happens once per thread, 
       // but potentially simultaneously
       lock(sync)
          result += threadLocalData.Results;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Reed - this does what I wanted, however I found a different way to tackle the problem. Nonetheless, this is excellent stuff that I will be using soon.

Comment: I wonder why they included such an ugly overload? At that rate it would be cleaner just to initialize thread-local data and deinitialize it in your main delegate. Unless they have perf-optimized it..?

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith The thread local data is reused across multiple delegate calls, so it can't be initialized/finalized inside a single delegate.  (That's the point ;) )

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution to the problem that doesn't require code. I was able to use CallContext to attach data to a "logical thread". This data is transferred from the starting thread to threads generated by TPL as well as the ThreadPool.

http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2010/09/27/logical-call-context-flowing-data-across-threads-appdomains-and-processes.aspx

Comment: Just FYI - This mechanism is much, much slower than using TLS, as it's serializing the data through each context call...

Answer (score 0):

There is, of course, yet another alternative:  Write a TaskLocal(T) class, like we did, that bases the storage on the current Task, rather than the current Thread.  Honestly, I have no idea why Microsoft didn't do this as part of their initial Task implementation.

Important Implementation note:  Because Task code that calls await can be split, and resume as a *different* TaskId, you also need to do what we also did, and implement a method in TaskLocal(T) that maps new TaskIds to previous ones, then save the original TaskId at the start of the Task, and map it after every await call.

Comment: A code sample demonstrating this would get a +1 from me :-)

Comment: I'll see what I can do...  (:

Comment: What about [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Why did none of us turn this up in our searches???  I'm off to compare `AsyncLocal<T>`'s behavior to our `TaskLocal<T>`.  I'll report back whether it compares favorably.