# TaskLocal<T> Class?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, async-await, task-parallel-library

We are looking to add TPL to a particular portion of our processes that are long-running and can be split into concurrent sub-processes.  The core issue that we are running into at this point is that our current code is dependent on an EntityFramework 6.1 DbContext which is not thread-safe.  I have spent some time digging into TPL and its innerworkings.  It doesn't appear that we can use ThreadLocal, as a Task can/will have multiple threads running on it throughout its lifetime (if I understand correctly) and the executing task will ultimately be interacting with multiple ThreadLocal instances.

The next thought I had around this is a TaskLocal object that could store the DbContext throughout the lifetime of the task (thereby cleanly separating it from other concurrent Tasks that are running this same code -- each with their own corresponding TaskLocal).

There is mention of something like this in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961233/how-to-manage-thread-local-storage-tls-when-using-tpl/31545882#31545882) but it does not offer any code or link to code.

Is this possible?  And also, is my understanding of TPL thus far correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, .NET already has one: [`AsyncLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.
Looks like this is what you want.